# Two identical post-methods, first is executed, second one is not allowed 405

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, controller

I just wonder what can go wrong

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<TokenDTO> login(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(loginService.login(loginDTO));
}

@PostMapping("/logout")
public ResponseEntity<?> logout(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {
    Guest guest = guestDao.getGuestByLogin(loginDTO.getLogin());
    guest.getTokens().clear();
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Logout successfully");
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthProvider)
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/guests/**", "/rooms/**", "/maintenances/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**", "/logout/**").permitAll();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB2RN.png) - /login executed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EN5v.png) - /logout 405 not allowed

Comment: I found that the problem is in the /logout endpoint. Is this reserved by spring?  .logout.logoutUrl() should help, thanks

Comment: try disabling logout `logout().disable()`